# Combined meta subsite sites

Tags: discussion

*This is probably not going to seem like a decent enough pitch, in length or quality, for what I am suggesting (which might very well have been suggested before, but I could't seem to find), but here goes:*

It would seem to me that a better model for meta sites of Stack Exchange, would be a single site for the entire network.

For meta subjects relative to all sub-sites, most sub-sites, or even a selection of sub-sites, this would allow easier:

1. Searching for
2. Reporting of
3. Linking of

... pre-existing proposals/information/conversations/bugs.

Small side advantage, there could finally be a http://meta.stackexchange.com site (Can you tell I am a fan of hierarchy?)

What does the community think?

****EDIT****

Due to the discussions that has ensued since, feel I need to clarify my question. I am not trying to suggest that the ability for any sub-site's community to have a level of control over their sub-site be taken away, only that the current system of meta-site-per-sub-site be changed to a single meta site, with (something) like Gmail's labels, instead of other e-mail clients folders, be used.

Comment: Would this be for reporting purposes?  All sites would still have their own meta site; I don't see that changing.  There has been discussion in the past about separating this site from SO, making it the site for general SE questions, and giving SO it's own meta site.

Comment: I could be completely off about this, but Meta Stackoverflow seems to serve in that capacity a lot of the time

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Not for reporting, at least not for me, right now. The imputus to create this question for me, was to stop me/other people having to search potentially multiple sub sites meta sites for previously addressed subjects, that may apply to what they are asking/their problem. Can also see it cutting down on the duplication I have seen sometimes. Lastly, if on one site, it could make clear (Through use of tags) which sites the question was asked about/the answers applied to; apaul34208 - I understand it does, but with other subsites having their own, a level of confusion seems to rein

Comment: Why would you need to search multiple sub-sites? Each site has enough autonomy to handle the majority of its own issues. If it is something systemic the SE team will likely need to get involved, but reporting a system issue on any Meta site should get their attention

Comment: @apaul34208 - The amount of times I have suggested something, on some other sub-sites meta site, and had someone refer to (most often) this meta site to a question already asked, is phynominal. As the auto-search-when-creating-a-title search on other meta sites, doesn't look at even this meta site, one has to manually search at least two meta sites, to do due diligence to establish prior asked questions.

Comment: @user66001 the reason is Meta.StackOverflow = Meta.StackExchange (for now).  If you have a specific question about a specific site (like why was this question closed, or can we retag [foo], or is foo-bar on topic) then you should be asking on that site's meta.  But if you have a question about how the system works or a feature request, then it should be on Meta.StackOverflow.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - In my experience, this subject isn't as simple as that.

Comment: @user66001 it should be that simple, so I think you need to provide some specific examples of your issue questions.

Comment: @user66001 RE: your edit.  Other than some vague assertions, you really haven't made a strong case for why this is needed.  So, why is this needed?  What problem are you trying to fix?  Do you have some specific examples that would have benefited from this change.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - Instead of duplicating content, perhaps you could read the comments to the other answers? As for any cases of benefits to this change, not sure I would use one users examples to justify such a large change.

Answer (score 12):

In a parallel universe somewhere, Bearded Stack Exchange creates meta sites as some sort of "view" of a larger Meta SE, with discussions related to individual sites separated by tags internally but with the ability to attach them to more than one site or every site.

...But in this universe, that's not possible. When there were only 3 sites, we kinda did it that way - but it never worked all that well, and as the individual communities grew it quickly became overwhelming.

So in this universe, we fake it with some handy guidelines:

1. If you have a feature-request, bug-report, discussion or support question, **post it on the meta site attached to whichever site you happen to be using.**
2. [Optional] If you know this discussion / report / request effects *multiple* sites, post it on MSO. If you don't know, or you just don't want to worry about it, just stick to your site's local meta.
3. Moderators (your site's representatives) or anyone else with similar levels of experience can take a per-site discussion or request and bring it to MSO at any time, should they decide it would benefit from a larger and more diverse audience.
4. The employees of SE monitor all meta sites, and have tools available to surface posts from any or all of them - that doesn't necessarily mean we'll interfere, but if something really critical gets reported on a child meta and not MSO, we'll probably still see it.

The only important guideline for most folks is #1 - if you see a problem or opportunity and *speak up about it*, that's enough for a start; most folks won't even do that. If you want to go above and beyond, there's certainly opportunity to do so - but it's not required, or even necessarily beneficial in most cases.

The truth is, *most* meta posts are fairly site-specific - the folks you want to consider them first are the folks who already know and respect you. So why waste that?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Shog9. Glad it has the highest votes. Diplomatic. Wish I lived in that parallel universe, I guess. Perhaps you can elaborate on some of the pitfalls I am obviously missing with how it evolved to be overwhelming? To address points I can think of in regards to the guidelines - 1. Doesn't allow pooling of ideas, with other communities who might be discussing changes that are currently site-wide; Makes finding good ideas that may apply site-wide, time consuming, 3. I have never seen this happen. 4. Good for them, not helpful for the communities knowledge however.

Comment: Perhaps this is the issue. Others feel that most meta posts could only apply to one sub-site, and I have the opposite opinion. In the end, think I will end up removing this question, as it appears everyone thinks there is more disadvantages than advantages, and I unfortunately care more about my reputation, than leaving this up for prosperity (Think I should find that meta suggestion that there is no rep on these sites, and +1 it). Unfortunately I am not the kind of person who feels he should stop at just what is required.

Comment: If I am understanding the last part, of your last sentence correctly, not sure anyone has really gotten to know anyone else here (Not like this is what the site is supposed to be about - It isn't a forum, after all), so by the same token, haven't gotten any indications that any respect is shared among the majority of members.

Answer (score 5):

Each site should have enough autonomy to handle the majority of its own issues. If it is something systemic the SE team will likely need to get involved, but reporting a system issue on any Meta site should get their attention.

Having separate Meta sites allows each site to handle things in a way that works for that community. For instance what works on say [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) may be wildly different than what works on [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) or [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Each site has its own issues and may need to come up with its own solutions to those issues.

Granted it is often helpful to refer to a per-existing working model when trying to solve a similar issue, but even then they should be free to say "... we like this part, but that part doesn't really apply here."

I would guess what you're running into is a "Don't reinvent the wheel attitude", which in some cases may be perfectly valid, but in others not so much. If it helps you make your point to see what other sites are doing or have done in the past look into it, but the status quo of one site shouldn't dictate how things are done on another.

**Edit in response to edit...**

If you're suggesting that there be a single Meta site and that each site have its own set of tags...

I think it would make for a pretty unpleasant user experience, we would be forced to search and sort through an awful lot of Q&A that many users would find irrelevant. I would guess that a great many SO users don't really care to know what is on-topic for Seasoned Advice, or what's bad etiquette on Photography.

I'm not entirely opposed to seeing a true Meta Stack Exchange, for system wide issues, seeing what the team is up to, and so forth, but I think combining all the Meta sites into a centralized Meta would cause more problems than it would solve.

Perhaps the [network wide search tool](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=off-topic) would do the job, if you would just like the ability to search all the Meta sites from one place.

(Can you tell I am ***Not*** a fan of hierarchy?)

Comment: I akin this to Gmail's labels, as opposed to folders (Hopefully most of the people reading this Q&A like Gmail!)...Actually, am going to write this into the question, I think this underpins my point nicely. I was not trying to suggest that sites don't handle their own things, just that it all be in a central place, and tags be used to differentiate specific site questions, from network questions. I think that it is completely justified that sites have scope to alter themselves for their community.

Comment: RE: Your edit - Who is the "we" in terms of searching and sorting through Q&A? I expect there is a selection of users who wouldn't care about most of the questions on even their communities meta site, but this is what search is for :) The problem with the SE setup, is there is a great deal of cross-sub-site relevant questions, which is really the reason why I think the issue exists, and needs to be displayed combined and categorised effectively.

Comment: @user66001 [like this?](http://stackexchange.com/search?q=off-topic)

Comment: Think there is a fundamental misunderstanding of my question. I am now regretting not spending the time thinking about as many possible angles people could be thinking about this. As for "Forcing" users to look through Q&A - Not sure how this is different to the status-quo. I know I see a whole bunch of questions in meta that don't interest me. However, this is what search tools like tags are there for, perhaps a checkbox system could be used instead.

Comment: That site wide search example ironically just appears to be returning meta.stackoverflow results, but as to the point, it still isn't as helpful as having all meta questions matching the title of your meta.stackexchange question, in one place. It also only address' my first point, not second or third. per se.

Answer (score 4):

Either you are over-complicating it or you have run into some strangely unique situations.

There is a very clear demarcation when it is appropriate to post on a specific site's Meta (Meta.Something.SE) or the main meta site (Meta.StackOverflow).  This can be somewhat confusing because (for historical reaons) Meta.StackOverflow does double duty as the meta site for Stack Overflow and Meta.StackExchange.  There is a plan to split off Meta.StackExchange as a separate site, but that is rather low priority and still in the planning stages.

Do you have a question about a specific sites policies or how something was moderated?  You need to be asking on that site's meta.

Examples of what should be posted on a site's meta

- Are you asking why a question was closed?
- Do you have a question about community moderation of a specific post
- Are you curious about whether a subject is on-topic or not?
- Do you have a retag request or want to find out info about a specific tag?

Examples of what should not be posted on a site's meta, and instead should go to Meta.StackOverflow (until Meta.StackExchange is finally split off)

- Bug reports
- Feature requests
- Discussions or support about functionality of the site

The reason is simple, the global community has no idea how/why a specific community works, so questions that are particular to that site need to be directed at that community.

What you are proposing (a combined Meta site for all subsites) is exactly why we have Meta.StackOverflow as the main Meta site for all of SE.  Originally this was the only meta so everything was posted here, but as the other sites became larger, and as the number of sites increased, it was clear that a combined meta was not sustainable, and the per-site metas were born.  What you are proposing is a return to what was tried and failed.

My biggest issue with this is you seem to think that just because a question is answered on another site's meta, that means it is a duplicate and shouldn't have been asked, or that you should be searching all meta sites for answers to your questions before asking.  I think this is an incorrect assumption.  Just because an issue I had on Math.SE happened to be answered on Meta.Physics.SE doesn't mean that the questions are actually duplicates.  It means you just happened to have 2 similar questions on 2 similar sites that choose to moderate something the same.

**TL;DR;**

In short, you don't need to search every meta.  Searching the subsite's meta for community moderation questions and MSO for SE-wide questions is all you need to do.

Comment: That's right, put the tl:dr at the bottom :P

Comment: @James Fair point - but I've almost always done that for some reason

Comment: well, tl:dr being at the top is not fair if you've written something decent and worthy of people reading it all..sometimes not possible either. I have almost re-written my entire post in tl;dr because the points couldn't be condensed.

Comment: Bug reports / feature requests / discussions are perfectly fine on any meta site. Sure, features and bugs with network-wide effects always have a place on MSO - but distinguishing between them is hard, and a fair number of them end up being support requests in the end anyway - it's not reasonable to expect most folks to make those decisions.

Comment: First, I wasn't around when there was only one meta site, so can't comment on improvements I/others who have come since may have seen to that structure, to try to not have had it fail (Your words). Most of the meta questions I post are feature suggestions, that could apply to many, if not all, of the sub-sites (Something I see I should have covered off in my question, given your bullet points above). As to the clear demarcation, not sure how much all answerer's have been following the comments of their counterparts, but I notice that it doesn't seem so clear what should go on each meta site.

Comment: In fact, every sub-site's meta I have used, has the ability to tag questions as features, bugs, or support, which seems to go against what I agree would be a better way to display these, than the status-quo. As to the single meta site in the past, I would be curious if anyone can elaborate as to how it failed in more detail. From what I have seen, there are a fair few duplicate questions on sub-sites (Not that I can present examples at this juncture).

Comment: As for not asking something that has already been asked, not sure about others, but I think a fair few meta posts I create could apply to any/all sub-sites. If others feel the same way, and post on their communities meta site, the very reason why duplicate questions are discouraged on individual communities, could cause potentially dozens of concurrent conversations on the same subject. To what I "need to do" - Part of my suggestion would save the need to search 2 sites. Had to google "tl;dr;" :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are asking is how it used to be, and something that is being changed to the opposite of what you propose.

The point of introducing separate metas for each site was so each site can handle it's own meta issues. To relieve the burden from meta.stackoverflow (MSO) a bit and so it's more logically structured.
People on (eg) superuser can deal with meta questions on meta.superuser, keeping relevant info grouped together, logically structured and easier to manage.

Then with MSO managing meta for the sites which don't have their own meta (ATM), and of course the meta for Stack Overflow (and for general Stack Exchange stuff ATM).

I see your point of duplicate info, and the huge amount of resources are already on MSO as it was *the* meta site for all for a long time.

I believe this is all being discussed at the moment, however.

Comment: _"The point of introducing separate metas for each site (only some atm)"_ - I was under the impression that _every_ site had its own meta, without exception, including beta sites. I'm not aware of a SE site that doesn't have a meta.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs I was under the impression only the "busier" ones were getting their own meta, but some research shows you appear to be correct.

Comment: Considering there seems to me to be so many suggestions/bugs/discussions/support subjects that are common between most sites in the network, then feel separating introduces it's own problems, in contrast to the advantages perhaps thought of when the split happened.

Comment: @user66001 At first, yes I agree it will be fiddly as MSO was the meta for all since whenever back when. But when this new way has been going for a while and all sites maintain their own meta without needing a central site (MSO), it'll be worthwhile. You shouldn't put off what would be a great and beneficial change because of potential teething problems and requirement for a bit of elbow grease ;)

Comment: Not sure we are on the same page. What happens if your suggestion applies to/you want to apply to, all sites? What about all programming-related sites? By the status-quo, you would (ideally) have to search a number of sub-sites meta sites to establish whether the suggestion, that could also apply to any combination of sub-sites again, has been previously made; Then you presumably could have someone who suggested on their communities meta, which may be intended to apply to the network (I don't have the time to search *every* meta to see if work on a question has already been done).

Comment: Lastly, as for the subjects that were discussed prior to the split in meta sites, these are not searched when asking new questions on any other sub-sites meta site, hence I can't easily count the amount of times I have had a meta.stackoverflow pre-existing question being referenced, on mine. Just doesn't seem as easy as much of the rest of the Stack Exchange Network.

Comment: @user66001 You're basing that on the premise that each site has enough questions/answers that would be beneficial to other sites. From what I see that's not the case. [Have a look for yourself](http://meta.superuser.com/questions). questions on a site's meta is relevant to that site. A question on that site, answer, comment, feature request, user, etc. Anything Stack Exchange wide would go here (ATM). But to have a meta for all sites for questions specific to different sites is how it used to be and from what I presume, the user base and total other sites simply outgrew this model.

Comment: @user66001 "I can't easily count the amount of times I have had a meta.stackoverflow pre-existing question being referenced" can you provide a few (at least 4) questions on another meta you venture which shows this please? They would all need to be within a short time frame of eachother.

Comment: That is exactly what I am basing this question on. Not sure how a link to general questions, is an example that this isn't the case. I feel that a fair few of my meta posts (Which are largely feature suggestions, either explictly, or not) could benefit a decent portion of the SE sub sites. Not sure the reason for your requirement of time frame. Duplicates seem to get marked as such on individual meta sites, years after the original un-closed question was asked. Unfortunately, though, I don't have the time to go and dig these up.

Comment: This question was more supposed to be about a principle I had thought that others could see to be an improvement. This seems to not be the case, so will probably be closing this question soon, to prevent hemorrhaging reputation that I should care about, but as it is a part of this site, I do.

Comment: @user66001 My requirement of time frame is because people on a non MSO meta getting linked to MSO only once every 2 weeks is not a regular occurrence. If you can provide examples all on the same day, or some within a day of each other then it's a regular occurrence! If you have examples perhaps post them here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202367/getting-data-from-mso-to-new-meta-sites-and-getting-people-to-use-the-other-met